# Return value of for() loop as if it were a function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apache-nifi

I have this `for` loop in an `R` script:

```
url <- "https://example.com"
page <- html_session(url, config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))

links <- page %>% 
  html_nodes("td") %>% 
  html_nodes("tr") %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")

base_names <- page %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>% 
  html_nodes("tr") %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>%
  basename()

for(i in 1:length(links)) {

  site <- html_session(URLencode(
    paste0("https://example.com", links[i])),
    config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))

  writeBin(site$response$content, base_names[i])
}
```

This loops through links, & downloads a text file to my working directory. I'm wondering if I can put `return` somewhere, so that it returns the document.

Reason being, is that I'm executing my script in NiFi (using `ExecuteProcess`), and it's not sending my scraped documents down the line. Instead, it just shows the head of my R script. I would assume you would wrap the `for` loop in a `fun <- function(x) {}`, but I'm not sure how to integrate the `x` into an already working scraper.

I need it to return documents down the flow, and not just this:

[image]

Processor config:

[image]

**Even if you are not familiar with NiFi, it would be a great help on the R part!** Thanks

Comment: Instead of a `for` loop, you can use `out <- Map(function(link, bn) { site <- ...link...; writeBin(..., bn); return(site$response$content); }, links, base_names)`. (BTW: you're missing the definition of `base_names`.)

Comment: Woops, fixed that names mistake @r2evans, my bad. What does the `bn` refer to in your comment?

Comment: `bn` is the arbitrary name I used as the second argument in the anonymous function; `Map` "zips" together the paired elements of `links` and `base_names`, assigning the first elements each to `link` and `bn` respectively within the function. If `lapply(links, function(link) {...})` works with just links, then `Map(function(link, bn) {...}, links, base_names)` is the equivalent with both.

Comment: So `Map(myfunc, links, base_names)` unrolls to `myfunc(links[1], base_names[1])`, then `myfunc(links[2], base_names[2])`, etc. `Map` always returns a `list`, whereas `mapply` *may* return a vector (analogous to `lapply`-vs-`sapply`).

Comment: I'm attempting to adapt your first comment (thanks for the logic of it, btw). I'm assuming I should get rid of the semicolons? Apologies for the dumb question. Not as familiar with `Map` as I should be. It's hard to picture with comment formatting. If you'd like to put in an answer, that would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is to both (1) save the output (with `writeBin`) **and** (2) return the values (in a `list`), then try this:

```r
out <- Map(function(ln, bn) {
  site <- html_session(URLencode(
    paste0("https://example.com", ln)),
    config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))
  writeBin(site$response$content, bn)
  site$response$content
}, links, base_names)
```

The use of `Map` "zips" together the individual elements. For a base-case, the following are identical:

```r
Map(myfunc, list1)
lapply(list1, myfunc)
```

But if you want to use same-index elements from multiple lists, you can do one of

```r
lapply(seq_len(length(list1)), function(i) myfunc(list1[i], list2[i], list3[i]))
Map(myfunc, list1, list2, list3)
```

where unrolling `Map` results effectively in:

```r
myfunc(list1[1], list2[1], list3[1])
myfunc(list1[2], list2[2], list3[2])
# ...
```

The biggest difference between `lapply` and `Map` here is that `lapply` can only accept one vector, whereas `Map` accepts one *or more* (practically unlimited), zipping them together. All of the lists used must be the same length or length 1 (recycled), so it's legitimate to do something like

```r
Map(myfunc, list1, list2, "constant string")
```

Note: `Map`-versus-`mapply` is similar to `lapply`-vs-`sapply`. For both, the first *always* returns a `list` object, while the second will return a `vector` IFF every return value is of the same length/dimension, otherwise it too will return a `list`.

Comment: No `return` before the last `site$response$content` in this case? Otherwise, I think this is a great showcase of what to use instead of a loop. Where can I send you a beer?

Comment: `return` is implied here ... use `return(site$response$content)` if you prefer

Comment: Got it.. if this returns a bunch of numbers, instead of document (scraping `.txt` files), is that wrong? (I really will send you beer money, I appreciate your patience)

Comment: is the return value different from the files created by `writeBin`?

Comment: Actually figured it out... it was dumping files in a random NiFi directory within the container (only could be seen through terminal). What I'm doing isn't ideal...but the client wants... so ya know