# How can I loop colnames as plot titles along with data using lapply in R?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, lapply

I have this function that works close to what I need -- it creates a clean table from my original raw data, makes it a ggplot, and uses `lapply` to run it through all the variables I want from the original table, `data`:

```
#Get colnames of all numeric varaibles
nlist <- names(data[,sapply(data,is.numeric)])

#Create function
varviz_n <- function(dat, var){
  var <- dat[,which(names(dat) == var)]

  title<-var

  tab <- dat %>%
    group_by(group = cut(var, breaks = seq(0, max(var), 10)),
             groupedsupport) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(group),n>10)

  tab2 <- tab %>%
    group_by(groupedsupport) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(freq),
              median = median(freq))

  finaltab <- tab %>% left_join(tab2, by = "groupedsupport")

  fplot <- finaltab %>%
    ggplot(aes(fill=group,x=groupedsupport,y=freq)) +
    geom_col(position="dodge") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste("n =",n), n = (n + 0.05)), position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust = 0, size=2) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(groupedsupport, ymax = median, ymin = mean),
                  size=0.5, linetype = "longdash", inherit.aes = F, width = 1) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    xlab("") + ylab("") +
    ggtitle(title) + 
    scale_fill_discrete("")

filename = filename <- paste0(finaltab$var)
ggsave(paste("Plots/",filename,".png"), width = 10, height = 7)

  return(fplot)
}

#Run function
lapply(nlist, varviz_n, dat = data)
```

This does almost exactly what I want -- the problem is that all of the variables it's running through are 0-100 numeric and it's creating the plots but I can't at all figure out how to get the column name as the title of the plot or of the key. So I have no idea which graph is getting returned.

Can someone please help me figure out a way to get the column name from `nlist` to be the title of my plot? The way it is now prints out the first value of the column instead of the actual column name:

[image: Exactly the graph I want with no title]

The final piece of code to save it in the 'Plots' folder doesn't work either since the title/var isn't populating correctly.

You can use something like this to create `data` to test out the code: `data <- data.frame(v1 = sample(1:100,1000,replace=T),v2 = sample(1:100,1000,replace=T),v3 = sample(1:100,1000,replace=T),groupedsupport = sample(LETTERS[1:3],1000,replace = TRUE))`

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you are using `lapply` (which operates on *one list*) and think you want to operate simultaneously on the corresponding elements in a second list/vector, think `Map`. See a previous related answer about `Map` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54485425/3358272

Comment: Take a look at `imap` or `iwalk` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902877/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114232/786542

Comment: @r2evans thanks! Are you saying I should use `Map` _instead_ of my `lapply` or is there a way to add it somewhere to my existing script just for the plot titles?

Comment: try flipping the two first lines of the function so that `title` gets assigned before you change the value of `var`

Comment: @Ryan, *replace*. `lapply(mydat, myfunc)` is analogous to `Map(myfunc, mydat)`, but if `myfunc2` takes two arguments, then `Map(myfunc2, mydat1, mydat2)` has no *direct* equivalent in `lapply` (though it can be crudely approximated with `lapply(seq_len(mydat1), function(i) myfunc2(mydat1[i], mydat[2]))`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to swap these steps:

```
var <- dat[,which(names(dat) == var)]
title <- var
```

should be

```
title <- var
var <- dat[,which(names(dat) == var)]
```

`var` being assigned to the column of selected data so when it is called again in `title`, it is looking at that vector and not the column name.

If this doesn't resole it, please give us some code to mimic the contents of `data`.

Comment: Actually OP is overwriting the *var* parameter, an ill-advised approach. Keep *var* as character param and use a different variable for data frame object or simply use *title* as function param: `varviz_n <- function(dat, title){ var <- dat[,which(names(dat) == title)] ...`