# How to create a column which which contains the name of the file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a loop which imports multiple files and merges them. I would like to find a way that during this process a new column is created called "filename" which contains the name of the input file that each row has come from.Is this possible?

Comment: Save the file name as a variable, in a vector of strings. Loop over each element of the vector of stings creating then naming a separate column vector and concatenating it to a matrix that was initialized as an empty matrix each time.

Comment: Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
my_data <- lapply(setNames(nm=my_files), read.csv)
my_data <- Map(function(x, nm), { x$filename <- nm; x; },
               my_data, my_files)
# or much more succinctly
my_data <- Map(transform, my_data, filename = my_files)
```

The first step (`lapply`) will produce a list of frames (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227). While not required, I also named the list with the filename. This might be handy at times, but is generally subsumed by the second step, adding the filename to the data.

The second step uses `Map`; `lapply` is to one list/vector what `Map` is to *one-or-more*, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54485425/3358272 for a walk-through of "unrolling" the call to `Map`. This second step just adds a column to each frame, and returns the frame.

After that, `my_data` will be a named list where the filename is both the name of the list element, and in a column `$filename` in each frame.